# Not is Null Syntax Error

Tags: sql

Can anyone please advise?  New to this...I was originally getting an "invalid is not null" error and after I modified I now get syntax error.

```
 'Add notes about employee
 strsql = "SELECT [Employee Number], Declination, Leave, Termed, Comments "
 strsql = strsql & "FROM tmpMHPP "
 strsql = strsql & "WHERE Declination Is Not Null"
 strsql = strsql & "or Leave Is Not Null Or Termed Is Not Null Or Comments Is Not Null"
```

Comment: You are missing a whitespace at the end of the third line (`WHERE Declination IS NOT NULL`), so these strings get concatenated as `…NULLOR…`.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a space. You need to add a space between Is Not Null and or

```vb
 strsql = strsql & "WHERE Declination Is Not Null "
                                                '^'
 strsql = strsql & "or Leave Is Not Null Or Termed Is Not Null Or Comments Is Not Null"
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed a space between

```
... Declination Is Not Null
```

and

```
or Leave Is Not Null ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This syntax help avoid these errors

```
strsql = "SELECT [Employee Number], Declination, Leave, Termed, Comments" & _
         " FROM tmpMHPP" & _
         " WHERE Declination Is Not Null" & _
         " or Leave Is Not Null Or Termed Is Not Null Or Comments Is Not Null"
```

Comment: You're not saying what the error is. ;) That being said, I do much the same thing, but I've got into the habit of putting whitespace both at the beginning *and* at the end of each line.

Comment: Its a simple typo so I mention this as an addendum and voted to close as simple-typo